# Tuleap how Delete items as project admin?

Tags: scrum, tuleap

i am using Tuleap for Scrum.

I am not able to delete any item even if i am project admin.

I create a new release (or a new sprint) by mistake... how to delete it?

the documentation does not mention it or it is quite well hidden.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I incidentally foudn the solution while playing on a test project: to delete an object i need to delete an artifact.

To delete a bug with ID 122 for example i need to go to
Trackers/Bug/Administration/Delete Artifact
and then type 122 in the editbox.

Comment: Wow, what a complex way to delete an item. Thanks.